# How to create custom cell with MessageKit?

Tags: ios, swift, chat, messagekit

I want to create  following custom chat bubble  using `MessageKit`

[image]

I am using `CustomCell` example in the provided sample. But that does not add the chat bubble background & positioning based on the sender type.

How to create the custom cell with the same chat bubble background ?

Answer (score 7):

### Creating a custom cell with [MessageKit](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit)

To make a custom cell, you have to make a cell that inherit from `UICollectionViewCell`. 
Once you have your cell, you need to tell the size of your cell. How can to do that ?

You have to make a class that inherit from `MessageSizeCalculator` or `CellSizeCalculator` to make a custom cell size calculator

You have to make a class that inherit from `MessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout` and add you custom size calculator that will calcul the size of your cell.

You must override two method to achieve that:

- `messageSizeCalculators()` to add your custom cell size calculator
- `cellSizeCalculatorForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath)` to choose with which cell you will use your custom cell calculator

You can see this example from the master branch:

```
open class CustomMessagesFlowLayout: MessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout {

    open lazy var customMessageSizeCalculator = CustomMessageSizeCalculator(layout: self)

    open override func cellSizeCalculatorForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CellSizeCalculator {
        let message = messagesDataSource.messageForItem(at: indexPath, in: messagesCollectionView)
        if case .custom = message.kind {
            return customMessageSizeCalculator
        }
        return super.cellSizeCalculatorForItem(at: indexPath)
    }

    open override func messageSizeCalculators() -> [MessageSizeCalculator] {
        var superCalculators = super.messageSizeCalculators()
        // Append any of your custom `MessageSizeCalculator` if you wish for the convenience
        // functions to work such as `setMessageIncoming...` or `setMessageOutgoing...`
        superCalculators.append(customMessageSizeCalculator)
        return superCalculators
    }
}

open class CustomMessageSizeCalculator: MessageSizeCalculator {

    public override init(layout: MessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout? = nil) {
        super.init()
        self.layout = layout
    }

    open override func sizeForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        guard let layout = layout else { return .zero }
        let collectionViewWidth = layout.collectionView?.bounds.width ?? 0
        let contentInset = layout.collectionView?.contentInset ?? .zero
        let inset = layout.sectionInset.left + layout.sectionInset.right + contentInset.left + contentInset.right
        return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth - inset, height: 44)
    }

}
```

You can take a look at this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/issues/945)

### Creating a cell based on MessageBubble with MessageKit

[MessageContentCell](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/blob/master/Sources/Views/Cells/MessageContentCell.swift) is the class used by [MessageKit](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit) to display your message in a chat bubble

You can create a cell by just extending this class:

```
import MessageKit
import UIKit

open class CustomCell: MessageContentCell {

     open override func configure(with message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath, and messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) {
         super.configure(with: message, at: indexPath, and: messagesCollectionView)


      }

     override open func layoutAccessoryView(with attributes: MessagesCollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
         // Accessory view is always on the opposite side of avatar
     }


  }
```

If you want to extend other [Cells](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/blob/master/Sources/Views/Cells)

Comment: API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x7fb114213740; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x60000392a6c0>> returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric....     Getting this error when keyboard opens in simulator.

Answer (score 2):

They have currently updated their documentation to include how to add a custom cell. Check it here
[Read more about custom cells](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/blob/master/Documentation/CUSTOM_CELLS.md)